# How to have two different makefile mapped to two different keys?

Tags: key-bindings, makeprg, compile-vim

I am using <kbd>F5</kbd> to compile my programs
From my `.vimrc`

```
set makeprg=make\ -f\ ~/makefile\ %<
noremap <F5> :make<CR>
```

But I want to add one other way to compile my programs which compiles a bit slowly and use some other key say <kbd>F4</kbd>. I tried inserting another such statement below these lines but then <kbd>F5</kbd> also compiles with the new makefile.

**EDIT**:
As asked in comments:

```
set makeprg=make\ -f\ ~/makefile\ %<
noremap <F5> :make<CR>
" slow compilation but more flags for more checks
set makeprg=make\ -f\ ~/makefile1\ %<
noremap <F4> :make<CR>
```

Comment: Can you show the `<F4>` binding? If you change `'makeprg'`, it affects all `:make` invocations

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Edited my question

Comment: Ok, yah, makeprg is just a setting. Mappings don’t save settings at their creation time.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this right way?

Comment: You're not actually changing the makeprg...it's always 'make'. Help says you can pass args to `:make` so can't you just do something like `nnoremap <F4> :make -f ~/makefile1 %` ?

Comment: Actually, it may look more like this (didn't notice the `%<` at first): `:noremap <F4> :exe "make -f ~/makefile1 " . expand('%<')<CR>`

Comment: @BLayer Thank you

Comment: Yes it works. Sure.

Comment: If you use `:make` a lot, check out the [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plug-in, which runs make in background for you. Also has separate `:Make` and a more general `:Dispatch` command to run arbitrary commands not constrained by `'makeprg'`.

Comment: will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that the `makeprg` setting is primarily used to change the actual make/build program and in your case the program isn't changing...it's always 'make'.

Since `:make` accepts arguments I suggest leaving `'makeprg'` alone and passing your build command args to `:make` in the two mappings...

```
noremap <F4> :make -f ~/makefile1 %<<CR>
noremap <F5> :make -f ~/makefile %<<CR>
```

Regarding `%<`, which expands to the current filename minus its extension, in my comments I wavered on whether this would work or if you would need to use `:exe` and call `expand()` like so....

```
noremap <F4> :exe "make -f ~/makefile1 " . expand('%<')<CR>
```

Actually, you should be okay with the shorter versions.

BTW, `%<` is there for backwards compatibility with a very old version of vim, per `:h :_%<`. The synonym, `:r`, is now "preferred".

Comment: ? I didn't get you

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: You bet. Cheers.